# Generate a data frame using apply function

Tags: r

i am new to R, i am trying to process each data frame column as an instance to return the each instace as a column in the data frame:

```
conFun <- function(x){
  t <- x[2]
  c <- x[3:8]
  c <- c[c != ""]
  w <- c(t,c)
  w <- paste(w, "H2", sep = "")

  tre <- data[, w[1]]
  con <- data[, w[-1]]

  if(length(c) > 2){
    mcon <- rowMeans(con)
  }
  else{
    mcon <- con
  }

  tre2con <- as.data.frame(mcon-tre) 
  names(tre2con) <- paste("inst_", x[1], sep = "")
  tre2con
}

res <- as.data.frame(apply(tre_con[1,], 1, conFun))
res

inst_1
2.27
-1.37
3.00
1.46
```

it work fine when i call `res <- as.data.frame(apply(tre_con[1,], 1, conFun))` only 1 row of `tre_con` data frame.

But when i call `res <- as.data.frame(apply(tre_con[3,], 1, conFun))` 3 rows of `tre_con` it only return the last row value like this:

```
res

inst_3
5.12
1.34
4.50
2.36
```

instead of:

```
inst_1  inst_2  inst_3
2.27    9.22    5.12
-1.37   2.14    1.34
3       6.12    4.5
1.46    -1.36   2.36
```

How can i achieve that using apply? or do i have to change the apply family function?

Comment: `res <- as.data.frame(apply(tre_con[1:3,], 1, conFun))` ?

Comment: `tre_con[3,]` is not 3 rows. It's just one row (the third row).  You probably want `tre_con[1:3,]`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks alot, that works fine. very easy to miss out such things.